# what do the OpenGL gl*Pointer functions do

Tags: c++, function, opengl

I've looked everywhere for exactly what the gl*Pointer functions do, i.e. `glColorPointer`, `glNormalPointer`, `glTexCoordPointer`, `glVertexPointer`. Nothing I've found is clear enough to describe what they manipulate - all I've found describes how they manipulate *it*, which doesn't help.

Basically, if OpenGL is an interface to create and manipulate objects, and each object has multiple functions to manipulate it, then just a function reference is terribly insufficient. There must be a description of the object. That I have not been able to find.

Could someone describe exactly what they are used for?

EDIT:

Heh, don't take me for a complete N00B ;-) Sorry I was unclear - when I say objects, I do mean abstract - very abstract. In fact, I categorize anything with a state and methods as an object - thus the gl*Pointer functions *set* a state that the glDraw* functions work with. I was just curious what the state exactly is.

EDIT:

[Here's the OpenGL function reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374211(v=vs.85).aspx) I've been using.

Comment: These were for old [client-side vertex arrays](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Client-Side_Vertex_Arrays), pre-dating VBOs. With the introduction of VBOs, `pointer` could be replaced with an `offset` into the currently bound VBO.

Comment: "*if OpenGL is an interface to create and manipulate objects*" There's your problem; your conclusion proceeds from a false premise. OpenGL has nothing to do with "objects" in a visual sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> OpenGL is an interface to create and manipulate objects

What kind of objects do you think of? State abstraction objects or geometrical objects like models? If you think of the later, i.e. objects in a scene, then you're in for a surprise: OpenGL doesn't deal with those.

OpenGL is a local state drawing API. You point to so some data buffer and batch some drawing commands and OpenGL will perform drawing operations based on the data it has been pointed to.

> Nothing I've found is clear enough to describe what they manipulate - all I've found describes how they manipulate it,

The `gl…Pointer` functions do not manipulate anything at all. They just tell OpenGL where to fetch data from, when a `glDraw…` function is called. `glDraw…` triggers the drawing (should be clear from the name) and the what is drawn is determined by the data found in the area of the buffer previously set with `glPointer…`.

There are no meshes, no higher order geometry, nothing. All OpenGL deals with are points, lines and triangles, which specification it draws one after another from data buffers, right at the time it is drawn. After OpenGL did draw a primitive it no longer cares about it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. For me it works ok, but for other people with the same question, you might want to add some more detail. E.g. what are the glDraw* functions, and what do they do.

But anyone who is wondering can just go to the link I provided above.